# Compiling of a Conditional Attribute

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I've been reading about conditional attributes, and I am still a bit confused as to what happens at compile time. Say I have the following code:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("FLAG")]
private void DoSomething(string myString)
{
    //  Do Something
}

public void Foo()
{
    DoSomething("With this.");
}
```

Assume that `FLAG` is not defined. When compiled, will the `DoSomething` method be a part of the assembly, or will it not exist? Assuming it does exist, will the call to `DoSomething` be commented out (or removed from the assembly), or will it call the `DoSomething` method and see that it is conditional and the condition has not been met so return immediately?

Obviously jumping to the method and returning without running would take more cycles than never calling it. This would not be an issue in most cases, but still seems like something worth knowing.

Comment: It exists, the only way that a compiler can discover the [attribute].  Which is why the MSDN article says "indicates to compilers that **a call** to the method should not be compiled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8) (emphasis and omission mine):

> Applying `ConditionalAttribute` to a method indicates to compilers **that a call to the method should not be compiled into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL)** unless the conditional compilation symbol that is associated with `ConditionalAttribute` is defined. **You will get a compilation error in Visual Studio if you apply this attribute to a method that does not return void.** [...]

So effectively, the call will disappear from the resulting binary.

Also:

> **Any arguments passed to the method or attribute are still type-checked by the compiler.**

Comment: Thank you. I read that, but it didn't quite click. So the method is there, but any calls to it are removed during the build.

Comment: @Tim: And, since there are no calls to the method, the method will never be JITted